# How to continuously trigger an apps script with a mouse click on a cell in googlesheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a matrix of stock symbols in A1:D20. I have a script to display the symbol in Cell D25. I want this display (run the script) each time I click in any cells of A1:D20. So, basically, I want the script to trigger at the click of the mouse. How do I do this?

Comment: but, I need to add button on all cells in A1:D20. If I have D100, then It is 400 buttons.

Comment: Take a look at onSelectionChange trigger

Comment: Also, I can't add button in the cells as these cells are color coded by conditional formatting to indicate Green or Red based stock trends.

Comment: "onSelectionChange" trigger - I will try this out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Cooper, Do I need Ui and or menu for this? should I say "addItem () under the function? I am familiar with creating menu and attaching the script to this. Not sure how to attach the script to this.

Comment: @Cooper - Thanks a lot. It works beautifully. Appreciate your input.

Comment: @Cooper - How do I restrict the trigger to A1:D20 ?

Comment: You cannot limit the trigger but you can limit how you respond in a manner similar to an onEdit() using the event object  which looks like this `{"range":{"columnEnd":7,"columnStart":7,"rowEnd":14,"rowStart":14},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{},"user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}`

Comment: @Cooper - After I added the below script it stopped working. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Like I said maybe you did not change "Sheetname" to your sheets name.  I assume that  you have a minimal knowledge of script editing.  This site is designed for programmers to help other programmers.  A programmer should be capable of editing their own code.  If you cannot do that, then this forum is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using onSelectionChange Event Object

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheetname" && e.range.columnStart < 5 && e.range.rowStart < 20) {
    //put your script in here
  }
}
```

This works for me if I change "Sheetname" to Sheet0

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart < 5 && e.range.rowStart < 20) {
    e.source.toast("In");
    sh.getRange("F4").setValue(e.range.getValue())
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you edit the Sheetname to you sheets name?

Comment: Yes, I did change to Sheet1(that is the name)

Comment: I wanted to show you the script here but the codes get wrapped.

Comment: var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r= s.getActiveCell();
  var v= r.getValue();
  var r2=s.getRange("F4");
  r2.setValue(v);

Comment: I inserted these lines into your script where it shows //put your script in here.

Comment: Yes in my last example I replaced all of that code with just one line so all you need to do is change the Sheetname and it should begin working

Comment: @Cooper-Thanks. I did update the script. Still not working. Can you try this? Fill-in B2:C4 with stock symbols and see whether you are getting the stock symbol in F4 when you click anywhere in b2:c4. If you click anywhere other than these cells the script shouldn't work, meaning you should see the last click symbol and not empty cell.